# JSON.parse: unexpected character error with ajax and json

Tags: java, jquery, json, knockout.js, struts2

I'm having some problem with Json. I want to send a json object to a database on a server and in return get a json result. I'm working with KnockoutJS, jQuery and struts-2.

This is javascript code:

```
function(ko, dataservice, config, router, messenger, Utente, Vario) {
    var
            logger = config.logger,
            utente = new Utente(),
            vario = new Vario(),
            isValid = ko.computed(function() {
        return utente.username() && utente.password() && utente.email();
    }),
            activate = function(routeData, callback) {
    },
            registrazione = function() {
        if (isValid()) {
            if (utente.password() === vario.password()) {

                dataservice.servizisegreteria.registrazione({
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result.esito === 'OK') {
                            router.navigateTo(config.hashes.registrazione);
                            logger.info("Controlla la tua casella mail!");
                        }
                        else {
                            logger.error("Salvataggio non riuscito!");
                        }

                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        logger.error("Controllare che i dati siano giusti!");
                    }


                }, $.toJSON({
                    'utente': {
                        'username': utente.username(),
                        'password': utente.password(),
                        'email': utente.email(),
                        'dataIscrizione': new Date()
                    }
                }));


            }

            else
                logger.error("Le Password devono combaciare!");
        }
        else
            logger.error("Inserire tutti i  dati!");
    };


    return {
        activate: activate,
        utente: utente,
        vario: vario,
        registrazione: registrazione
    };
}
```

This is code for ajax request:

```
var init = function() {
        amplify.request.define('registrazione', 'ajax', {
            url: '/VenditaGioielli/gestioneSegreteria/nuovoUtente.action',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
    },

            registrazione = function(callback, data) {
        return amplify.request({
            resourceId: 'registrazione',
            data: data,
            success: callback.success,
            error: callback.error
        });
    },

    init();

    return {   
        registrazione: registrazione

    }
}
```

This is html code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<section id="registrazione-view" class="view">
<div id="container">

    <div id="contenuto">
        <div class="formGioiello">  

            <div class="gruppoInput">

                <div>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" data-bind="value: utente.username"  required/>  
                </div> 
                <div>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" data-bind=" value : utente.password" required/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Ripeti Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Ripeti Password" data-bind="value :vario.password" required/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" data-bind="value :utente.email" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button data-bind="click: registrazione, jqueryui: 'button'">Registrati!</button>
            </div>
        </div> 

    </div>
</div>
```

this is struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="segreteria" namespace="/gestioneSegreteria" extends="json-default">

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="segreteriainterceptor" class="it.lt.venditagioielli.gestioneSegreteria.web.GestioneSegreteriaInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-stack name="gestionesegreteriastack" >
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="segreteriainterceptor"/>
        </interceptor-stack>     
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="gestionesegreteriastack"/>

    <global-results>
        <result name="nonloggato" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <action name="nuovoUtente" class="it.lt.venditagioielli.gestioneSegreteria.web.GestioneUtenteAction" method="inserisci">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="gestionesegreteriastack" />
        <result type="json">
            <param name="root">esito</param>
        </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

And this is the action code:

```
  package it.lt.venditagioielli.gestioneSegreteria.web;

  import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
  import it.lt.venditagioielli.gestione.model.Esito;
  import it.lt.venditagioielli.gestione.model.Utente;
  import it.lt.venditagioielli.gestioneSegreteria.servizi.ServiziSegreteria;

  public class GestioneUtenteAction {
    private Utente utente = new Utente();
    private Esito esito = new Esito();
    private ServiziSegreteria serviziSegreteria;
    private String idUtente;

    public String inserisci() {
        try {
            serviziSegreteria.inserisciNuovoUtente(utente);
            serviziSegreteria.inviaMailConferma(utente);
            esito.setEsito("OK");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            esito.setEsito("KO");
        }

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }

    public Esito getEsito() {
        return esito;
    }

    public void setEsito(Esito esito) {
        this.esito = esito;
    }

    public Utente getUtente() {
        return utente;
    }

    public void setUtente(Utente utente) {
        this.utente = utente;
    }

    public void setServiziSegreteria(ServiziSegreteria serviziSegreteria) {
        this.serviziSegreteria = serviziSegreteria;
    }
    public String getIdUtente() {
        return idUtente;
    }

    public void setIdUtente(String idUtente) {
        this.idUtente = idUtente;
    }
  }
```

I'm getting  this error while getting data from database:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character error

in fact, netbeans doesn't even get to the `GestioneUtenteAction` class on debug mode!

The json object sent is

```
{"utente":{"username":"luca","password":"l","email":"ho@ho.it","dataIscrizione":"2013-11-04T13:30:09.575Z"}}
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

EDIT: the action isn't hit, and the answer from the server is my html page, instead of a json object. This html is  given to the parseJSON function of jquery. I came to this result by comparison whit another working action

Comment: If you're getting a JSON parsing error, the first thing to do is look at the JSON being returned (in the Network tab of your browser's dev tools) and make sure it's valid. And if it is, post the valid JSON to the question.

Comment: `return {   
        registrazione: registrazione,

    }` ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios, i erase the comma!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the post metod  of the action on Firebug doesn't have a returned json, but only a json send!

Comment: @LucasTegliabue That's what we need to see--the JSON being sent.

Comment: @DaveNewton, i added the json object to the question, but i'm quite sure that is correct, other action whit same json layout works. Thanks

Comment: The JSON itself is validated. What do you mean by the error happens while you're "getting data from the database"? If the action isn't even being hit, is there a validation error? Are there any funky characters in the JSON? What's different between the action that works and the one that doesn't, in terms of action properties, configuration, ...?

Comment: i'm not sure, but i think that there is a problem whit the invocation of the action or the parsing of the json to send.

Comment: Other actions are quite similar, i still don't see errors!

Comment: `the action isn't hit, and the answer from the server is my html page, instead of a json object`: if the Action isn't hit, who is answering from the server ? A static resource ?

Comment: Your Interceptor Stack is very poor: 3 interceptors :/ Try adding at least the **basicStack**, or the **defaultStack** to the others in your custom stack, and see if it changes somehow.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, where can i see who is answering? i also tried to add the defaultStack, but nothing changed

Comment: Thanks @AndreaLigios for showing the way. it was a problem whit the interceptor and the session. i mean, a problem of logical implementation!